# Using Spring Integration Router with Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have been trying to use the Spring Integration's [@Router](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/annotation/Router.html) with Spring Cloud Stream with Kafka binding. My understanding is that when you return a `List` of channel names from the method annotated with `@Router` they should be produced to the destined Kafka topics. But I don't see the messages being produced.

Does Spring Integration's `@Router` work with Spring Cloud Stream. If not, what's the alternative and how do I programmatically route to channels selected at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What makes you believe that Spring Integration `@Router` has any effect in Spring Cloud Stream? It's a completely different framework.

Yes there are mechanisms to route FROM and TO in Spring Cloud Stream and they are described [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_event_routing).

I think the specific section of interest to your use case is [Routing FROM](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_routing_from_consumer), but consider reading the full section to understand the differences and mechanisms used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Apparently I was under the impression SI and SCSt components work together since SCSt is based on SI. I was wrong. Thank you for clarifying. I tried `BinderAwareChannelResolver` and it works as expected. However I am curious if we can actually route to bindings and not to topics. `BinderAwareChannelResolver` expects the channel name/topic. Is it possible to use the binding name instead?

Comment: You are routing to bindings. In a case of BinderAwareChannelResolver the channel and binding name is the same

Comment: So if I’ve a binding name ‘fooBar-01’ with destination ‘foo.kafka.topic’ and if I use BinderAwareChannelResolver with ‘fooBar-01’, would it send/produce the message to ‘foo.kafka.topic’? And if I have a @StreamListener on binding ‘fooBar-02’ with same destination ‘foo.kafka.topic’, would it get invoked/consume the message?

Comment: yes if you map binding to destination via `destination` property